# Limitar Input de números Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usando o seguinte código quero limitar de 0 a 2000 o número que poderá ser informado pela varável **num**

```
import collections
num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))    #Inputar número inteiro
binario = bin(num)[2:]     #Cortar o 0b
sequence = binario
collection = collections.Counter(sequence)
print('O número binário de {} é {}'.format(num,binario))
print('A maior sequência de 0 é {}'.format(len(max(binario.split('1'), 
key=len))))
```

Seria limitar o número a ser inputado na variável num.

Answer (score 4):

Basta fazer uma condição:

```
if 0 <= num <= 2000:
    # Faça algo
```

Se quer solicitar ao usuário uma nova entrada enquanto o valor for inválido, precisará de um laço infinito:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input())
        if not 0 <= num <= 2000:
            raise ValueError('Valor fora do intervalo permitido')
        break
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```